# What is the "User" role in Azure Agent Pools?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In the documentation page [Create and manage agent pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser), there's a table listing the different security roles related that are available for agent pools.

It's divided to "Roles on an agent pool in project settings" and "Roles on an agent pool in organization settings".

In the "Roles on an agent pool in project settings", there's a role "User":

> Members of this role can use the project agent pool when authoring pipelines.

I can't understand what this means.
First, it's not very clear what it means to "Author a pipeline".
Let's assume that it means creating a build definition. If so, then in order to "author" a pipeline a user must be in the "Build Administrators" group, and the "Build Administrators" group is automatically assigned a "Administrator" role on each agent pool in the project:
[image]

Turns out so, that if you have the permissions to author a pipeline (again, assuming that it means creating a build definition), you're automatically assigned an "Administrator" role on that agent pool.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

Author a pipeline means that when creating a pipeline you could use this agent with the user role on the agent pool in project settings. For example, when you first run a yaml pipeline using this agent, you need to  have user permission to permit it:

[image]

In order to create a pipeline, users do not need to be in "Build Administrator". Give user **Edit build pipeline** and **Queue builds** permission by setting pipeline permission in Pipeline >> Manage security button. Then user can create pipelines and save any changes to a build pipeline, including configuration variables, triggers, repositories, and retention policy. Please refer to [Pipeline permissions reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#pipeline-permissions-reference).

Comment: Very unclear answer

Comment: @YoavKlein Sorry, I accidentally pressed the send button, while I'm still editing my answer. I'll leave a comment when it's updated.

Comment: @YoavKlein Hi, I have updated my answer. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: you did help me realize that I can have a user being able to create pipelines without being a "User" of the agent pool, but the answer is still not good. I'm upvoting, but won't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JaneMa-MSFT, I realized that I can allow the user to create pipelines without being a member of the "Build Administrators" - one easy way is to assign it as a member of the "Contributors" group, which by default has permissions to create pipelines, so it is a possibility to be able to "author" a pipeline, and yet not have "User" role on the agent pool.

So what I found out is, that it doesn't really matter who "authored" the pipeline - i.e. created it. The effect of being a "User" on that agent pool (in the project level) is the ability to permit the pipeline to use that agent pool. By the way - if that agent pool is marked as "Grant access permissions to all pipelines" - this role doesn't have any meaning for that pipeline!